# Ubuntu 14.04 Installing Numpy and Scipy without Root Access

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu, numpy

A remote server that I used for python development recently migrated to Ubuntu 14.04 and it has broken my numpy and scipy installation. I do not have root access and everything I have tried has resulted in failure. So far I have:

1) Tried to install numpy from source built with the system version of python. This gives a PyUnicodeUCS2_FromUnicode error which I believe is because the system version uses ucs4. As I do not have root access I do not know if there is anything I can do about this.

2) Tried to install numpy using pip. This gives an error saying that it cannot find the Python.h header file that is included in python-dev. Again, I have no root access so cannot install python-dev.

3) Tried to create a virtual environment and install a new version of python. Initially I got a httpsrequest import error which meant I couldn't use pip but I was able to install from source. However when I then installed scipy and tried to import a module, I got the error that a libgfortran library was not found.

I've spent the last day trying to find a solution to this but everything I try seems to encounter an error somewhere. I also don't want to have to install to much stuff (i.e. dependencies) in my home directory to get this to work as I only have a limited amount of space. Any ideas on how I could proceed?

Comment: If you don't have python-dev, I don't think you're going to get far installing numpy from source (unless you have python3-dev).  One thing that might work is building numpy and scipy elsewhere (e.g., a VM on a local system) and copying the result over, but you'll have to provide binaries (i.e., build from source) *everything* that is missing on the remote machine.

Comment: The interesting thing is that I was able to build numpy and scipy from source but this gave me the ucs2/ucs4 error. It was only when I used pip that I got the python-dev error so I assume it wasn't looking in the correct place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered using an 'all-in-one' package for scientific computing with Python, such as

- [Canopy](https://www.enthought.com/products/canopy/)
- [Anaconda](https://store.continuum.io/cshop/anaconda/)
- [Miniconda](http://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/)

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have enough space for the standard anaconda installation. Are there any smaller all-in-one packages?

Comment: I found miniconda and this worked for me in terms of space and functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried downloading Sage?  You can just use it as an Ipython system if you want (`sage -ipython`) and then import numpy and scipy.

There [seems to be a binary for 14.04](http://boxen.math.washington.edu/home/sagemath/sage-mirror/linux/64bit/sage-6.2-x86_64-Linux-Ubuntu_14.04_x86_64.tar.lzma), though I don't know the specifics of your platform.

(This does have the downside that it is a very large install, of course, so it may not suit your needs, but it should make it easy, anyway.)

Comment: I actually have sage installed on another server but do not have enough space on this one.