# Python not working on Ubuntu 14.04 (trusty) - Can't import standard library

Tags: python, ubuntu

After completely uninstalling python on the server and reinstalling `python` and `python-dev`, Python is behaving in a faulty way. The most apparent bug is that I am unable to import a number of modules from the standard library. For example, I cannot import the datetime and encodings modules.

```
[sloria@osf-staging ~]$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 22:59:56)
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import datetime
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named datetime
>>> import encodings
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named encodings
```

This makes it impossible to use pip, virtualenv, etc. Why might this be happening?

**Edit**: Here is the output of `dpkg -l | grep python`:

```
[sloria@osf-staging python2.7]$ dpkg -l | grep python
ii  dh-python                            1.20140128-1ubuntu8                 all          Debian helper tools for packaging Python libraries and applications
ii  libpython-dev:amd64                  2.7.5-5ubuntu3                      amd64        header files and a static library for Python (default)
ii  libpython-stdlib:amd64               2.7.5-5ubuntu3                      amd64        interactive high-level object-oriented language (default python version)
ii  libpython2.7:amd64                   2.7.6-8                             amd64        Shared Python runtime library (version 2.7)
ii  libpython2.7-dev:amd64               2.7.6-8                             amd64        Header files and a static library for Python (v2.7)
ii  libpython2.7-minimal:amd64           2.7.6-8                             amd64        Minimal subset of the Python language (version 2.7)
ii  libpython2.7-stdlib:amd64            2.7.6-8                             amd64        Interactive high-level object-oriented language (standard library, version 2.7)
ii  libpython3-stdlib:amd64              3.4.0-0ubuntu2                      amd64        interactive high-level object-oriented language (default python3 version)
rc  libpython3.3-minimal:amd64           3.3.2-7ubuntu3.1                    amd64        Minimal subset of the Python language (version 3.3)
ii  libpython3.4-minimal:amd64           3.4.0-2ubuntu1                      amd64        Minimal subset of the Python language (version 3.4)
ii  libpython3.4-stdlib:amd64            3.4.0-2ubuntu1                      amd64        Interactive high-level object-oriented language (standard library, version 3.4)
ii  python                               2.7.5-5ubuntu3                      amd64        interactive high-level object-oriented language (default version)
ii  python-apt                           0.9.3.5                             amd64        Python interface to libapt-pkg
ii  python-apt-common                    0.9.3.5                             all          Python interface to libapt-pkg (locales)
ii  python-chardet                       2.0.1-2build2                       all          universal character encoding detector
ii  python-colorama                      0.2.5-0.1ubuntu1                    all          Cross-platform colored terminal text in Python - Python 2.x
ii  python-dev                           2.7.5-5ubuntu3                      amd64        header files and a static library for Python (default)
ii  python-distlib                       0.1.8-1                             all          low-level components of python distutils2/packaging
ii  python-html5lib                      0.999-2                             all          HTML parser/tokenizer based on the WHATWG HTML5 specification (Python 2)
ii  python-minimal                       2.7.5-5ubuntu3                      amd64        minimal subset of the Python language (default version)
ii  python-pip                           1.5.4-1                             all          alternative Python package installer
ii  python-pkg-resources                 3.3-1ubuntu1                        all          Package Discovery and Resource Access using pkg_resources
ii  python-requests                      2.2.1-1                             all          elegant and simple HTTP library for Python, built for human beings
ii  python-setuptools                    3.3-1ubuntu1                        all          Python Distutils Enhancements (setuptools compatibility)
ii  python-six                           1.5.2-1                             all          Python 2 and 3 compatibility library (Python 2 interface)
rc  python-support                       1.0.15                              all          automated rebuilding support for Python modules
rc  python-twisted-core                  13.2.0-1ubuntu1                     all          Event-based framework for internet applications
ii  python-urllib3                       1.7.1-1build1                       all          HTTP library with thread-safe connection pooling for Python
ii  python2.7                            2.7.6-8                             amd64        Interactive high-level object-oriented language (version 2.7)
ii  python2.7-dev                        2.7.6-8                             amd64        Header files and a static library for Python (v2.7)
ii  python2.7-minimal                    2.7.6-8                             amd64        Minimal subset of the Python language (version 2.7)
ii  python3                              3.4.0-0ubuntu2                      amd64        interactive high-level object-oriented language (default python3 version)
ii  python3-apparmor                     2.8.95~2430-0ubuntu5                amd64        AppArmor Python3 utility library
ii  python3-dbus                         1.2.0-2build2                       amd64        simple interprocess messaging system (Python 3 interface)
ii  python3-gdbm:amd64                   3.4.0-0ubuntu1                      amd64        GNU dbm database support for Python 3.x
ii  python3-gi                           3.12.0-1                            amd64        Python 3 bindings for gobject-introspection libraries
ii  python3-libapparmor                  2.8.95~2430-0ubuntu5                amd64        AppArmor library Python3 bindings
ii  python3-minimal                      3.4.0-0ubuntu2                      amd64        minimal subset of the Python language (default python3 version)
ii  python3-newt                         0.52.15-2ubuntu5                    amd64        NEWT module for Python3
ii  python3-pkg-resources                3.3-1ubuntu1                        all          Package Discovery and Resource Access using pkg_resources
ii  python3-problem-report               2.14.1-0ubuntu3.2                   all          Python 3 library to handle problem reports
rc  python3.2                            3.2.3-6ubuntu3.5                    amd64        Interactive high-level object-oriented language (version 3.2)
rc  python3.2-minimal                    3.2.3-6ubuntu3.5                    amd64        Minimal subset of the Python language (version 3.2)
rc  python3.3                            3.3.2-7ubuntu3.1                    amd64        Interactive high-level object-oriented language (version 3.3)
rc  python3.3-minimal                    3.3.2-7ubuntu3.1                    amd64        Minimal subset of the Python language (version 3.3)
ii  python3.4                            3.4.0-2ubuntu1                      amd64        Interactive high-level object-oriented language (version 3.4)
ii  python3.4-minimal                    3.4.0-2ubuntu1                      amd64        Minimal subset of the Python language (version 3.4)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23714254/ubuntu-14-04-installing-numpy-and-scipy-without-root-access

Comment: Show the output of `dpkg -l | grep python`

Comment: The python-dev package typically just includes things you need to build C extensions, not python itself. It's surprising you even have an interpreter anymore if you "uninstalled python".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, I figured it out. I had inadvertently disallowed access to C standard library files for non-root users by calling `chmod -R 770` on my application's virtual environment. It turns out that the standard library modules in a virtual environment which are not pure Python (e.g. the `datetime` module) symlink back to the system Python's `.so` files. So changing the permissions on the virtual environment also changed the permissions of the corresponding modules in the system Python.

Therefore, I was able to fix the problem by running `chmod -R 775 /path/to/virtualenv`.

[facepalm]

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu (and Debian for what I can tell) come with two python packages by default: `python` and `python-minimal`. I guess that what happened is that you removed the first one, but as the second dont depends from it you still have a somehow working prompt.

As the name implies this is a very minimal version of python, with a very limited number of libraries included. You should be able to run some simple scripts, but nothing more.

The `python-dev` package contains files needed to compile extensions (you may need it further while installing packages from pip), but does not replace the interpreter.

To get back on track you just need to install again the "full" python version:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-2.7
```

This only install python back, not any already installed libraries that were removed in the process. To get a listing of what was removed you can inspect the output of `/var/log/apt/history.log`. You will see entries similar this one:

```
Start-Date: 2014-04-21  12:29:19
Commandline: apt-get remove python3.4-dev
Remove: python3.4-dev:amd64 (3.4.0-2ubuntu1), python3-dev:amd64 (3.4.0-0ubuntu2)
End-Date: 2014-04-21  12:29:30
```

I don't know what made you remove python, but that usually is a bad idea. There are some applications that depend on that explicit python version (and the libraries bundled with them), and this is especially true in the desktop version. Of course you can install other python versions, just make sure they don't replace the main one.

Comment: I reinstalled python2.7, but I still get the same error. The only reason I uninstalled python in the first place was because I was getting those import errors.

Comment: What is the output of `dpkg --get-selections | grep python`. You can use something like http://pastebin.com if the output is very long

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem with the same symptoms, which I solved by reinstalling `python3`'s `stdlib`:

```
apt-get install --reinstall libpython3.4-stdlib
```

Answer (score 0):

If you get the following error:

```
 /etc/init.d/apparmor: 35: .: Can't open /lib/apparmor/functions
```

## Try the following: (skip to solution if it does not work)

Task: Stop Apparmor

Type the following command:

### debian/ubuntu

```
 sudo /etc/init.d/apparmor stop
```

### Suse

```
 /etc/init.d/boot.apparmor stop
```

Task: Start Apparmor

Type the following command:

### debian/ubuntu

```
 sudo /etc/init.d/apparmor start
```

### Suse

```
 /etc/init.d/boot.apparmor start
```

Task: Restart Apparmor

Type the following command:

### debian/ubuntu

```
 sudo /etc/init.d/apparmor restart
```

### Suse

```
  /etc/init.d/boot.apparmor restart
```

Task: See the current Apparmor status

Type the following command:

### debian/ubuntu

```
 sudo /etc/init.d/apparmor status
```

### Suse

```
 /etc/init.d/boot.apparmor status
```

as instructed on: 
    http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/suse-ubuntu-linux-start-stop-restart-apparmor-command/

If you happen to experience any problems with the AppArmor, 1st reinstall the files you purged/uninstalled prior to the problem & then just run this command. It will resolve it. it worked on my Ubuntu 15.10.

## Solution:

```
  sudo apt-get install --reinstall -u AppArmor
```